# Open multiple files from urls using xarray and open_mfdataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray

I'm trying to download multiple CMIP6 datafiles from 2015-2050, for high resolution wind gusts.
There are 432 files in total in the dataset taken from [here](https://esgf-data.dkrz.de/search/cmip6-dkrz/) (see screenshot for search terms used to narrow it down).

There are 432 files in this, and I can open them individually by right-clicking the OpenDAP Download button (highlighted in red on screenshot) and pasting the url into the `open_mfdataset` function like this:

```
ds = xarray.open_mfdataset(('http://esgf-data3.ceda.ac.uk/thredds/dodsC/esg_cmip6/CMIP6/HighResMIP/CMCC/CMCC-CM2-VHR4/highres-future/r1i1p1f1/6hrPlevPt/sfcWind/gn/v20190509/sfcWind_6hrPlevPt_CMCC-CM2-VHR4_highres-future_r1i1p1f1_gn_201501010000-201501311800.nc',
                             'http://esgf-data3.ceda.ac.uk/thredds/dodsC/esg_cmip6/CMIP6/HighResMIP/CMCC/CMCC-CM2-VHR4/highres-future/r1i1p1f1/6hrPlevPt/sfcWind/gn/v20190509/sfcWind_6hrPlevPt_CMCC-CM2-VHR4_highres-future_r1i1p1f1_gn_201502010000-201502281800.nc'))
```

This works fine, but there are 432 files and it would take a very long time to do this - I have tried other methods but feel that there is a way I can use xarray to do this efficiently that I am missing - I would really appreciate some help. Thank you.

EDIT:
I got it to work using the 'THREDDS Catalog' link in the screenshot below and the following code:

```
df = pd.read_html('http://esg.lasg.ac.cn/thredds/catalog/esgcet/180/CMIP6.HighResMIP.CAS.FGOALS-f3-H.highresSST-future.r1i1p1f1.6hrPlevPt.psl.gr.v20200521.html#CMIP6.HighResMIP.CAS.FGOALS-f3-H.highresSST-future.r1i1p1f1.6hrPlevPt.psl.gr.v20200521', skiprows = 1)

df = df[0]

#get all relevant (432 files)
df = df[:432]

#add the url to each datafile to create a downloadable link for each
df['url'] = 'http://esg.lasg.ac.cn/thredds/dodsC/esg_dataroot/CMIP6/HighResMIP/CAS/FGOALS-f3-H/highresSST-future/r1i1p1f1/6hrPlevPt/psl/gr/v20200521/' + df['CMIP6.HighResMIP.CAS.FGOALS-f3-H.highresSST-future.r1i1p1f1.6hrPlevPt.psl.gr'].astype(str)

filelist = df['url'].tolist()

#do the first 10 to see if it works (change the number)
test = filelist[:10]

#do the first 10 into a dataset
ds = xarray.open_mfdataset(test)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we learned we can not use wildcard operators in order to access data from an openDAP server. But we can take advantage of the regular structure of the CMIP model output files and build the file name manually:

```py
import calendar
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

# base url
base_url = 'http://esgf-data3.ceda.ac.uk/thredds/dodsC/esg_cmip6/CMIP6/HighResMIP/CMCC/CMCC-CM2-VHR4/highres-future/r1i1p1f1/6hrPlevPt/sfcWind/gn/v20190509/sfcWind_6hrPlevPt_CMCC-CM2-VHR4_highres-future_r1i1p1f1_gn_'

# period of interest
pr = pd.period_range(start='2015-01',end='2050-12', freq='M')

file_list=[]
for dt in pr:
    # get recent year and month
    year = dt.strftime('%Y')
    month = dt.strftime('%m')

    # get last day of month (no leap years in CMIP)
    last_day_of_month = str(calendar.monthrange(dt.year, dt.month)[1])
    if last_day_of_month == '29':
        last_day_of_month = '28'
        
    # build complete file name
    single_file=(base_url+year+month+'010000-'+year+month+last_day_of_month+'1800.nc')
    file_list.append(single_file)
    
ds=xr.open_mfdataset(file_list)
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you - when I try this I get the following error: `ValueError: cannot do wild-card matching for paths that are remote URLs: 'http://esgf-data3.ceda.ac.uk/thredds/dodsC/esg_cmip6/CMIP6/HighResMIP/CMCC/CMCC-CM2-VHR4/highres-future/r1i1p1f1/6hrPlevPt/sfcWind/gn/v20190509/sfcWind_6hrPlevPt_CMCC-CM2-VHR4_highres-future_r1i1p1f1_gn_*'. Instead, supply paths as an explicit list of strings.`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated my answer with another (less elegant but working) approach which I tested for 2015 - 2025.

Comment: Thank you again for this - unfortunately now I get the following error: `OSError: [Errno -37] NetCDF: Write to read only: b'http://esgf-data3.ceda.ac.uk/thredds/dodsC/esg_cmip6/CMIP6/HighResMIP/CMCC/CMCC-CM2-VHR4/highres-future/r1i1p1f1/6hrPlevPt/sfcWind/gn/v20190509/sfcWind_6hrPlevPt_CMCC-CM2-VHR4_highres-future_r1i1p1f1_gn_201703010000-201703311800.nc'`

Comment: Does this error occur regardless of the period you select?

Comment: Yes I've tried it with down to 5 years and still get the same error.

Comment: Hm..two further ideas:
* It works for me with Python 3.7.3 and xarray 0.16.0 so you could try these package versions
* is the error message always for the same file? What happens if you exclude it from the list `pr`.

Comment: Thanks again - I'm using python 3.8.5 and it did not work for me. I have edited my question to show a workaround which I did get working for a few files, but I get the `write to read only` error above when I go over ~20 files, which I am assuming is due to memory limitations on my computer.

Comment: This could be a reason yes. Do you have access to a HPC system? This could work, or you store every 20 files as one nc on your local computer and `mfdataset` those files

Comment: I do not have access to HPC currently, I try to get around it! Thanks again for your help.